# iOS6 Safari in web-app mode leaves "ghost" umlaut dots

Tags: html, web-applications, ios6

In my demo web app at http://dtmp.vm-dg.de/ori/app.html#view-location/locid-1/catid-0 I have a problem: When running the app in Web App mode from the home screen instead of inside Safari and then click on one of the categories, then the umlaut dots from the Ü in the title will "stay" there on iOS 6. (I don't have an iOS7 device and actually don't intend on upgrading)

I have put the two screenshots showing the bug at https://www.dropbox.com/s/forfzxfqm1i1295/bug1.jpg (menu screen) and www.dropbox.com/s/fiym7qwz6i9xo5x/bug2.jpg.

I have not managed it so far to nail it down to a testcase, though. Anyone ever experienced a similar problem?

Comment: I'd suggest you to start narrowing down the CSS by removing property by property to see when umlaut dot rendering issue disappears. You've used quite an extensive set of properties and values like -webkit-calc. This is a nasty "rendering bug", but these come across unfortunately often with iOS Mobile Safari, although I haven't run into this particular one.

Comment: Will do so - do you know by chance why the problem doesn't appear in Safari? Does iOS use two different WebKit engines for Safari and WebApp mode?